# Accessing Razor Page Route Data

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to get the route data for a razor page to do some processing in app.use depending on the razor page being requested. How do I get the name/action for the razor page being served. In MVC i have used the context.Request.RouteValues to get to the controller and action methods. Can you please guide me to an equivalent when using razor pages.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no controller/action in Razor pages . If you want to access the route data , you can use :

```
var datas = RouteData.Values;

//get page name/path 

var path  = RouteData.Values["page"];
```

If you have route Data parameters which are defined in a Route Template as part of the `@page` :

```
@page "{title}"
```

You can get the value like :

```
var title = RouteData.Values["title"];
```

In addition , you can also get the page name/path from HttpContext :

```
var path = HttpContext.Request.Path;
```

If you have handler to redirect url like :

```
<a asp-page="Privacy" asp-page-handler="Menu2" asp-route-id1="p02" asp-route-id2="123">Menu 2</a> |
```

You can get handler using :

```
var handler = HttpContext.Request.Query["handler"];
```